# Is T a linear transformation?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let T: $M_{2x2} \rightarrow M_{2x2}$ be defined by

T(A) = $\begin{bmatrix}
       1 & 3          \\[0.3em]
       -1 & 1         \\[0.3em]
\end{bmatrix} A $

Is T a linear transformation?

I want to show that the operations for linear transformations hold. However, I am not sure if I am on the right track for showing that the linear transformation is closed under addition. Let A and B be 2x2 matrices with components in $\Re$.

Let A = $\begin{bmatrix}
       a & b          \\[0.3em]
       c & d         \\[0.3em]
\end{bmatrix}$ and B  = $\begin{bmatrix}
       e & f          \\[0.3em]
       g & h         \\[0.3em]
\end{bmatrix}$.

T(A + B) = $T\begin{bmatrix}
       a & b          \\[0.3em]
       c & d         \\[0.3em]
\end{bmatrix}$ + $T\begin{bmatrix}
       e & f          \\[0.3em]
       g & h         \\[0.3em]
\end{bmatrix}$ = $T\begin{bmatrix}
       a+e & b+f          \\[0.3em]
       c+g & d+h         \\[0.3em]
\end{bmatrix}$. Not sure what to do at this point.

T($\alpha$A)= $\alpha$ $\begin{bmatrix}
       1 & 3          \\[0.3em]
       -1 & 1         \\[0.3em]
\end{bmatrix}A$ = $\begin{bmatrix}
       \alpha1 & \alpha3          \\[0.3em]
       -\alpha1 & \alpha1         \\[0.3em]
\end{bmatrix}A$ = $\alpha T(A)$

Comment: I don't follow your reasoning for $T(A + B)$. I think the order of your deductions should have been (left, right, middle) rather than (left, middle, right).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have:

$$T(A + B) = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 3 \\ -1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}(A + B)$$

Note that matrix multiplication distributes, so we get:

$$T(A + B) = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 3 \\ -1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}A +  \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 3 \\ -1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}B = T(A) + T(B)$$

Comment: Ahh.. I see where I went wrong. Thanks, your illustration makes it very clear where my confusion was.

Comment: Glad I could help! :-)

Answer (score 3):

It should be given in your text at some point that matrix multiplication satisfies the following properties (among some other important ones): for compatible matrices $A,B,C$ and scalar $\alpha$:

- $A(B + C) = AB + AC$
- $A(\alpha B) = (\alpha A)B = \alpha(AB)$

That should be enough to prove what you need to prove.

Comment: The first property made it clear where my confusion was. Thanks for the reminder.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you've already proved everything you desire to; you've got it in the wrong order though; you ought to write out $T(A+B)$ as the sum of two matrices (as you do on the rightmost expression) and *then* note that this equals $T(A)+T(B)$ (as you do in the middle expression). (Your proof that $T$ preserves scalar multiplication is fine)

Comment: Thanks, your answer and the accepted answer really made it clear what my confusion was.